# "I would hate anything to happen to her" vs. "I would hate if anything should to happen to her"

Tags: grammaticality, ellipsis

I have a question regarding the sentence found in the song "Girlfriend in a coma" by The Smiths, and the song goes:

> There were times when I could have strangled her
>   But you know,
>   **I would hate anything to happen to her**
>   Would you please let me see her...

Shouldn't the structure look more like this? :

**I would hate if anything should to happen to her**

Or is this just a shortened version of what I feel is correct?
(I know that these are song lyrics, and it might just be that Morissey wanted the words to fit the rhythm of the song).

Comment: Also, "I would hate *for* anything to happen to her.

Comment: Also *I would hate **it** if anything were to happen*.

Comment: Whilst agreeing with @FumbleFingers, "I would hate anything to happen to her", is idiomatic.

Comment: It's 'if anything should happen' - the 'to' is unnecessary.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I would agree that there is more than one way to skin a cat!

Answer (score 2):

Your instinct is on point, the preferred, formal way to express this thought is "I would hate if anything were to happen to her." However, in everyday speech, an English-speaking person would likely say "I would hate for anything to happen to her." In this song, the word "for" has been omitted, but it remains understandable.

Comment: Worth noting that this phrase is used idiomatically as a threat.  "Nice car you have there.  Be a shame if anything were to happen to it." Because it implies that there is a likelihood that something bad *will* happen to it.  An English speaker wanting to avoid that implication would say something like, "I hope nothing bad happens to her."

Comment: @BenJackson It *can* be a threat, but it doesn't *have* to be a threat.